# Placing dot on number line (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I created a number line. But I want to place a dot on the number line (one shaded circle) and the other (open circle). For example, shaded circle on 2 and open circle on -3.

Code I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=stealth,
every node/.style={align=center,scale=.8}] 
\draw[cyan,line width=2pt] (-5,0)--(5,0);
\foreach \i in {-5,...,5}
\draw[teal] (\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below]{\i};
\draw[<-] (0,-.6)--++(-90:.3) node[below]{The\\ origin};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
\draw[fill=white] (-3,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2 ,0) circle (3pt);
```

[image: Result]